# How to shorten my code to write a simple text file?

Tags: python

My data as variables:

```
Brazil = 55
USA = 12
Greece = 32
India = 56
```

Now, I wanted to produce the text file as shown below:

```
Brazil 55
USA 12
Greece 32
India 56

with open ('result.txt','w') as fo:
  fo.write('Brazil' + ' ' + str(Brazil) + '\n')
  fo.write('USA' + ' ' + str(USA) + '\n')
  fo.write('Greece' + ' ' + str(Greece) + '\n')
  fo.write('India' + ' ' + str(India) + '\n')
```

My code works, but how can I shorten it?  I am using Python 2.7

Comment: This site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as inspectorG4dget but using the newer style string formating (which I think is a bit clearer and easier to use):

```
import collections
vals = collections.OrderedDict([("Brazil", 55), ("USA", 12), ("Greece", 32), ("India", 56)])
with open('result.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for country,score in vals.iteritems():
        fo.write("{} {}".format(country, score))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import collections
vals = collections.OrderedDict([("Brazil", 55), ("USA", 12), ("Greece", 32), ("India", 56)])
with open('result.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for country,score in vals.iteritems():
        fo.write("%s %d\n" %(country, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, 1-line shorter and without imports:

```
dict = {'Brasil':55, 'USA':12, 'Greece':32, 'India':56,}
with open("result.txt", "w") as fd:
    for c in dict:
        fd.write("%s %d\n" % (c, dict[c]))
```

**Edit:** I had tested with print instead of fd.write

@Burhan Khalid, I raise you the 2-liner:

```
dict = {'Brasil':55, 'USA':12, 'Greece':32, 'India':56,}
open("result.txt", "w").write("\n".join(['%s %d' % (c, v) for c,v in dict.iteritems()]))
```

And may GvR forgive us for not explicitly closing a file...

Also, from here on the one liner is obvious, just include the dict in the list comrehension.

Answer (score 0):

Three line version:

```
d = {'Brasil':55, 'USA':12, 'Greece':32, 'India':56}
with open('result.txt', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(a, b) for a,b in d.iteritems()))
```